# Google Apps Script - Processing data from a filtered table

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently working on a Google Sheets document on which I have to create a macro to compare data in different sheets. Since it is a rather large file, I want to filter the data before comparing them. However, when I perform the filter, I cannot process the filtered data anymore.

```
function PREC_CHECK(msn, mydate){

  //Initialising Data
  var i = 2;
  var prec_check = new Date("01-Jan-2007");
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var serviceDates = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Service Dates.csv");

  // Getting last row and last column
  var lastRow = serviceDates.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = serviceDates.getLastColumn();

  //Extracting Data
  var originalData = serviceDates.getSheetValues(2, 2, lastRow, lastCol);

  //Filtering Data
  var filteredData = originalData.filter(function(item){
    return (item[3] == msn);
  })

  while (filteredData.getRange(i, 2).getValue() != "")
  {
    if (filteredData.getRange(i, 5).getValue() == msn && filteredData.getRange(i, 15).getValue() > prec_check && filteredData.getRange(i, 15).getValue() < mydate )
    {
      prec_check = filteredData.getRange(i, 15).getValue();
    }
    i++;
  }
  return prec_check;
}
```

I filter the lines according to the "msn" then in the "while" loop I want to compare "mydate" to the dates contained in each filtered row.

The error message (which I understand in itself) line 21 is :

> TypeError: filteredData.getRange is not a function

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to capture the data from your sheet you need this:

```
var originalData = serviceDates.getRange(2, 2, lastRow, lastCol).getValues();
```

This way you will get the 2d array `originalData`.

2. If you want to get values from this array (from the cell (i,2), for example) it can be done this way:

```
var value = filteredData[i][2];
```

As for the error: `filteredData` is an Javascript array that you just made. It has no methods `getRange()` and `getValue()`.

The `getRange()` is a method of the Sheet object and `getValue()` is a method of the Range object.

Unfortunately I hardly can help you further since I don't understand your code.